# When should we use a DbSet with EF Code First

Tags: database, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

As the title says, when should we declare a property of type DbSet for an entity, General Guidelines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no general guidelines. Instance of `DbSet<YourEntity>` is your access point to loading and persisting entities of a given type. If you don't expose the property on your context type you can still create it on the fly by using `dbContext.Set<YourEntity>()`.

The only difference between exposing and not exposing the property is in entity discovery during defining the model. When EF is first use it builds "the model" for defined entities. Entities are discovered through:

- Mappings explicitly defined on `DbModelBuilder` instance
- Configuration types explicitly registered in `DbModelBuilder` instance
- `DbSet<>` properties defined in context type
- Types referenced by already discovered entities

So if you don't use `DbSet<>` properties you must tell EF about your entities with other methods.

Comment: It is the last point you mentioned that confuses me, if entities are discoverable by reference then why would we need to put them in a DbSet<EntityType>.

Comment: If you don't use first two options and you for example use mapping by conventions or through data annotations you always need to tell EF at least about your root entities so that it can discover other through references.